# Can't Enable button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, entity-framework, telerik

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   function Enable_Butt() {               
         document.getElementById("<%=RadButton1.ClientID%>").disabled = false; // Doesn't Work                                                      
   }
</script>
```

i also tried this and still not work //$find("<%=RadButton1.ClientID %>").set_enabled(true);

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton1" runat="server"  SingleClick="true" SingleClickText="Processing..." AutoPostBack="true" OnClick="Create_Order_Click" Text="Create Order" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="12" BackColor="#333333" ForeColor="White" Skin="Bootstrap" CssClass="auto-style5"  >
    </telerik:RadButton>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="5000" ></asp:Timer>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="RadButton8" EventName="Click" />
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
   </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e){
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), " ", "Enable_Butt()", true);
}
```

Comment: You have to use your developer tools to verify that your JavaScript code is really asking for the same id value as what is in the actual DOM. Are you getting an error reported in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the `disabled` attribute to `false`, just remove it:

```js
function Enable_Butt() {
  document.getElementById("button").removeAttribute("disabled");
}

 document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", Enable_Butt)
```

```html
<button disabled id="button">Button</button>
<button id="b">Enable</button>
```

Comment: Setting the `disabled` *property* to `false` on the element node works too.

Comment: That's right! HTML just doesn't seem to care what the attribute says.

Comment: @Pointy that's not correct. See [HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#concept-fe-disabled) where it says 
"A form control is disabled if its disabled attribute is set, [...]"

So you actually need to remove the _disabled_ property to enable it properly.

Comment: @Meikel you can quite easily check for yourself with a quick jsfiddle. The HTML5 spec is about HTML, not the DOM. The DOM element node *property* dynamically controls it.

Comment: @Pointy That's correct. Browsers may support more than the specs say but you should not rely on that. For example this only works in JS. Putting a `disabled="false"` does not work!

Comment: @Meikel You're reading the wrong spec, and adding a `disabled` **attribute** is not the same thing as manipulating the DOM.  The HTML parser follows the HTML spec to parse HTML source code and build the DOM data structure. Once that's done, what's important is the W3C DOM spec, where you'll find a description of the `disabled` **property** of interactive elements.

Comment: [Here is the DOM Level 2 HTML spec for the `HTMLButtonElement` interface.](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-34812697) Note the `disabled` property, and note that the type of the property is `boolean`.

Comment: it didn't work also , but i found the problem which is in telerik button itself 
but it works perfectly with the standard button
~Thanks Guys